# Best way to deploy a ERC20Token to the mainnet

Tags: solidity, wallets, contract-deployment, erc-20

I'm planning on deploy a ERC20 Token Contract to eh Main-net. I've tested it on both Rinkeby and Ropsten, deploying from different platforms. Parity,Ethereum Wallet, Remix with metamask. I wanted to ask based on previous experience, what platform/mean do you guys recommend to deploy the token.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank @Artyom Lisovskij for your reply! Does anyone has any  experience while deploying with another option apart from remix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of them. I prefer Remix because it is online IDE, not just client.